# How to sort pixels and implement linearGradient in webgl histogram?

Tags: opengl-es, html5-canvas, webgl, linear-gradients

I was trying to implement a histogram for a image using webgl.
I am able to do it in javascript HTML5 Canvas by taking a array of 255 length and increasing pixel values of each index through out 0-255 and using createLinearGradient to create a histogram.

```
for(var c = 0; c < 256; c++){
    histogram[c] = 0;
}
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var pixels= ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < u8a.length; i++, j = j + 4) {
    histogram[pixels[j]]++; //increasing pixel index for histogram
}
```

And for implementing the same in WebGL, I am referring this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/9amgpndt/) but what I see is the histogram is not smooth and not sorted.

So, I am stuck with 2 things here with WebGL:

-How can we sort the pixel values from 0.0(0) to 1.0(255) in the above mentioned fiddle?

-How to make the histogram smooth in webgl with/without linear gradient?

Code :

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_histTexture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_maxTexture;
void main() {
    // get the max color constants
    vec4 maxColor = texture2D(u_maxTexture, vec2(0));
    // compute our current UV position
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    // Get the history for this color
    // (note: since u_histTexture is 256x1 uv.y is irrelevant
   vec4 hist = texture2D(u_histTexture, uv);
   // scale by maxColor so scaled goes from 0 to 1 with 1 = maxColor
   vec4 scaled = hist / maxColor;
   // 1 > maxColor, 0 otherwise
   vec4 color = step(uv.yyyy, scaled);
   float rr = 0.2989 * color.r + 0.5870 * color.g + 0.1140 * color.b;
       gl_FragColor = vec4(rr, rr, rr, 1);
}
```

[image: Histogram ranging from 0 to 255 or 0 to 65536 if image is 16 bit]

Comment: ?? Sort a histogram!, not really a histogram if it is sorted. Anyway your question is very unclear, what do you mean by smooth and sort? can you provide an image of what you want, including unsorted and sorted histograms as it is hard to guess what you mean?

Comment: from sorting what I mean is it should render from 0.0 to 1.0 from darkest to lightest (black to white) in grayscale format. I will shortly add the expected image

Comment: added image , please check, I am currently using createLinearGradient of Html5 Canvas for this result

Comment: To create gradient change last line to `gl_FragColor = vec4(rr, rr, rr, 1.0) * vec4(uv.xxx,1.0);` it will multiply the color by the x position (0-1) As for sort, that is still unclear as to what you mean.

Comment: ok I tried your change and it looks good .Thanks . For the sorting thing, please check the image I added, it starts from darker shades and goes to lighter shades . Hope that's clear.

Comment: The image gives no clue what is sorted?

Comment: Can't you see brighter colours from the left to lighter colours to the right

Comment: I see a wavy line and dark left to light right. I don't see bright to light (though I don't know what the difference is between bright and light, maybe you mean saturation for bright??), The code you show (link) has dark to light (left to right) That is what a histogram is, x axis is brightness/lightness, y axis is count. Can you show the sort you use for the 2D context version.

Comment: For 2D, I used a array of 256 elements, starting from 0 to 255. So while iterating the pixel values in the code above in post I just increment the index . Hence if there are 100 0's as pixel value in the whole image, I make index 0 to 100(code : histogram[0] = 100) and same thing applies until 255(code : histogram[n] = pixelCount). And to make the histogram smooth, I used colorStop i.e. `    var myGradient = histCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, histCanvas.width, 0);
    myGradient.addColorStop(0, 'black');
    myGradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
    drawHistogramPath(histCtx, myGradient);  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best i can work out is that you dont want to sort, but rather you want to do a black and white histogram (all channels r,g,b combined).

To do that you need just one pass that sums all channels rather than 4 passes as it currently does.

You need to make changes to the following shaders and replace a some render calls in javascript.

#### Change "hist-vs" to

```
attribute float pixelId;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
  vec2 pixel = vec2(mod(pixelId, u_resolution.x), floor(pixelId / u_resolution.x));
  vec2 uv = (pixel + 0.5) / u_resolution;
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
  float colorSum = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0 ; 
  gl_Position = vec4((colorSum * 255.0 + 0.5) / 256.0 * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.5, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
```

#### Change "max-vs" to

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
  vec4 maxColor = vec4(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    vec2 uv = vec2((float(i) + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5);
    maxColor = max(maxColor, vec4(texture2D(u_texture, uv).rgb, 1));
  }
  gl_FragColor = maxColor;
}
```

#### Change "show-fs" to

```
precision mediump float;    
uniform sampler2D u_histTexture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_maxTexture;    
void main() {
  vec3 maxColor = texture2D(u_maxTexture, vec2(0)).rgb;
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
  vec3 hist = texture2D(u_histTexture, uv).rgb;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(step(uv.yyy, hist / maxColor) * uv.x, 1);
}
```

#### Changes to javascript

Then in Javascript rather than call the first shader 4 times you need only call it once. Also as the mask uniform is not needed you dont need to pass that to the shader.

The for loop that originally looked like

```
  for (var channel = 0; channel < 4; ++channel) {
    gl.colorMask(channel === 0, channel === 1, channel === 2, channel === 3);
    twgl.setUniforms(histProgramInfo, {
      u_texture: tex,
      u_colorMult: [
        channel === 0 ? 1 : 0,
        channel === 1 ? 1 : 0,
        channel === 2 ? 1 : 0,
        channel === 3 ? 1 : 0,
      ],
      u_resolution: [img.width, img.height],
    });
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.POINTS, pixelIdBufferInfo);
  }
```

replace all those lines with

```
gl.colorMask(true, true, true, false);
twgl.setUniforms(histProgramInfo, {  u_texture: tex,  u_resolution: [img.width, img.height]});
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.POINTS, pixelIdBufferInfo);
```

Comment: This solution works as expected but it does not create a linear gradient as per the image I attached(see the black line covering the histogram from top). So, does that mean that OpenGL cannot render a linearGradient like what we achieve from a HTML5 Canvas createLinearGradient?

Comment: @subhfyu546754 You need to use the correct terminology. The black line is a stroke, and has nothing to do with a gradient.

Comment: yes it's a stroke I didn't notice. But how do we achieve it in webgl in this scenario . I can see many examples online , but can you give some idea on how to implement stroke in this case

Comment: @subhfyu546754 The fiddle provided is not conducive to adding an outline and the stroke you show extends outside the webGl canvas. You can easily use 2D API`globalCompositeOperation` (gCO) and the webGL rendered image as a mask to draw an outline  but you will need to modify the WebGL output to include transparent pixels. Then create a new canvas that is one pixel bigger on all sides, draw the mask 1 pixel up,down,left and right, set gCO to "source-atop", draw a black rect over the canvas, set gCO to "source-over" and draw the mask at the center.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks for the idea. Am accepting this as a answer